# Why is the rbf kernel much faster than linear kernel for sklearn cross validation?

Tags: python, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am doing a cross validation on a sample set of 250(7 dimensions).
Like:

```
55.56,1165,92,12.66,107180,46.92,69.04  1
55.56,1165,92,12.66,107180,46.92,69.04  1
57.78,265,74,3.58,19610,45.25,69.48 1
48.65,645,81,7.96,52245,30.33,13.81 0
33.33,717,67,10.7,48039,35.57,52.85 0
97.56,514,68,7.56,34952,83.98,33.28 0
```

I'm confused why the result comes out immediately when using rbf kernel, but it takes rather more time when using linear kernel.

Is this correct?

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1)
#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, features_train, labels_train, cv=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1, gamma = 0.01)
```

Comment: Please document your answer. Publishing just code doesn't teach anyone.